# Prove an element of $\Bbb Z_n$ has order $n$ iff it is invertible.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, ring-theory, finite-groups

I am trying to prove that an element of $\Bbb Z_n$ has order $n$ (additively) iff it is invertible (multiplicatively).

I cannot see why the $2$ operations have this relationship, and I have stuck on it for some time. So may I please ask for a proof or at least some possible way to approch the problem? Thanks!

**EDIT** : Now I think I am done with one direction. So may I please ask if someone could tell me how can I see the fact that if an element is invertible, then it has additive order $n$? Thanks so much!

**EDIT'**: Now I think maybe I've got it, so may I please ask for a proof verification?

From the comment below:

For $⇐$ direction: If $p$ is invertible, then $∃q∈\Bbb Z_n$ such that $pq=1$. Now we investigate what is the minimum number $x$ such that $xp=0$: Once $xp=0$, ,we have $xpq=0$(That is, to have $xp=0$ we must have $xpq=0$), and as $1$ has order $n$ in $\Bbb Z_n$, the least number $x$ to allow $xpq=0$ is $x=n$. Thus the order of $p$ is at least $n$, also $p∈\Bbb Z_n$, so the order of $p$ divides $n$, so the order is exactly $n$.

And for  $⇒$ direction: If $p$ is not invertible, there exists a non-zero number $x$ such that $xp=0$, and in $\Bbb Z_n$, we know that $x$ ranges from $0$ to $n−1$, so $x=n$ is not the least number to allow $xp=0$, $n$ is not the order of $p$.

May I please ask if I have got it correct? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Denote by $g$ any element of $\mathbb Z_n$ of order $n$. Consider the map $\phi:\mathbb Z_n\to \mathbb Z_n$ defined by $\phi(x)=gx$. Why is this map injective, hence bijective?

Comment: Does the injectivity from the fact that: consider $ker\phi$, $\phi(x)=gx=0$ for some $x\in \Bbb Z_n$ iff $x=n=0$. Is that correct? So what can  I see from that?

Comment: Oh is that the fact that as it is bijective, exist an element of $\Bbb Z_n$ such that the product is 1?

Comment: $injective \implies bijective$ when the source and target are finite and of euqal cardinality

Comment: I see, but may I please ask for the other direction. That is: given that an element is invertible, prove that it have order $n$?

Comment: if $p$ is a unit there is $q$ (also a unit) for which $pq \equiv 1 \mod n$. So $xpq \equiv 0 \mod n$ means $x=n$. This would not be necessary if there was an $m < n$ for which $mp \equiv 0 \mod n$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
For if $n$ is **prime**, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a finite field. Every non zero element in a field is a unit (invertible) and no element (other than $1$) divides $n$.

So the above holds for **all** (execpt $0$) elements, if $n$ is **prime**.

Comment: I am not given that $n$ is a prime and not working in a field. Also if possible, could you please have a look at the edited question?

Comment: The hint was: "So whats so special about primes?" (So all elements in the quotient have what you are looking to prove?)

Comment: Sorry I tried still cannot figure out how to do this... I wonder how to use prime as a tool to prove the general case. May I please ask for a more explicit explanation?

Comment: I see your comment in the other answer. So is that the fact that what I ask to prove is not nacessarily true for non-prime n?

Comment: In the common above, are you saying that for $\Rightarrow$ direction: If $p$ is invertible, then $\exists q\in \Bbb Z_n$ such that $pq=1$. Now we investigate what is the minimum number $x$ such that $xp=0$: Once $xp=0$, ,we have $xpq=0$, and as $1$ has order $n$ in $\Bbb Z_n$, the least number $x$ to allow $xpq=0$ is $x=n$. Thus the order of $p$ is at least $n$, also $p\in \Bbb Z_n$, so the order of $p$ divides $n$, so the order is exactly $n$?

Comment: And for $\Leftarrow$ direction, do you mean that: If $p$ is not invertible, there exists a non-zero number $x$ such that $xp=0$, and in $\Bbb Z_n$, we know that $x$ ranges from $0$ to $n-1$, so $x=n$ is not the least number to allow $xp=0$, $n$ is not the order of $p$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a\in \mathbb{Z}_n$ of order $n$ additively, this means that
$$
a + a + \ldots + a = a n = 0
$$
and such $n$ is minimal meaning that for all $1\leq k<n$ we have $a k\neq 0$. Suppose by contradiction that there exists $k\neq j$ such that $a k = a j$. Let $k>j$. We see that
$$
ak=aj \quad \iff \quad a(k-j)=0 \quad \iff\quad am=0 \quad m=k-j<n
$$
which contradicts the minimality of $n$. Therefore $k\neq j$ implies $ak\neq aj$. So that there are $n$ distinct numbers $ak$, $k=1,\ldots,n$. Which means that $\# (a\mathbb{Z}_n)=n$, along with $a\mathbb{Z}_n \subset \mathbb{Z}_n$ and $\#(\mathbb{Z}_n)=n$ implies $a\mathbb{Z}_n = \mathbb{Z}_n$. Then there exits $1\leq k<n$ such that $ak=1$.